# Proof verification: proving an improper integral exists

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification, improper-integrals

I am a bit rusty on formally proving the existence of improper integrals. I did a somewhat simple proof, but it feels sketchy and incomplete. I was hoping someone could verify it.

**Problem:** Suppose $f,g:(0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfy the following:

1. $g,f \in \mathcal{R}$ (Riemann-integrable) on $[t,T]$ for any $0<t<T<\infty$,
2. $|f| \leq g$,
3. $\int_0^\infty g(x)dx$ converges.

Show $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ converges for any $a>0$.

**Proof:**
Let $a>0$. Choose $N \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ with $a \leq N$. Remark $0 \leq |f| \leq g$ implies $\int_t^T g(x)dx \geq 0$ for any $0<t<T<\infty$. Also note $\int_0^\infty g(x)dx = \int_0^N g(x)dx + \int_N^\infty g(x)dx$. Since $\int_0^\infty g(x)dx$ converges and $0 \leq |f| \leq g$, then $\int_N^\infty g(x)dx$ must converge. By the integral test, it follows $\sum_{n=N}^\infty g(n)$ converges. Since $|f| \leq g$, it follows $\sum_{n=N}^\infty |f(n)|$ converges. Therefore $\sum_{n=N}^\infty f(n)$ converges, and so $\int_N^\infty f(x)dx$ exists. Note $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx = \int_a^N f(x)dx + \int_N^\infty f(x)dx$. Recall $f \in \mathcal{R}$ on [t,T] for any $0<t<T<\infty$. Then $\int_a^N f(x)dx$ exists. Therefore $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx = \int_a^N f(x)dx + \int_N^\infty f(x)dx$ converges. $\square$

Is this proof good? Are there any incorrect statements or jumps of logic? Thank you.

Comment: your proof is not right, you can use the integral test only if the functions are monotone, but this is not the general case here. A hint for you: show that $$\left|\int_a^\infty f(x) dx\right|\leqslant \int_a^\infty |f(x)|dx\leqslant \int_0^\infty |f(x)|dx\leqslant \int_0^\infty g(x) dx$$ for any $a\geqslant  0$

Comment: @Masacroso   Thank you. I forgot about that. I believe I found out how to, using the fact that for a sequence $(b_n)$ that diverges infinity, there exists some $N \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $\left| \int_{b_m}^{b_n} f_k \ dx\right| \leq \int_{b_m}^{b_n} g \ dx<\epsilon$ for $n,m \geq N$ and $b_m \leq b_n$. Is this the right track?

Comment: @Masacroso I have another question. I wrote that $\int_0^\infty g \ dx=\int_0^b g \ dx + \int_b^\infty g \ dx$. Is this something I can assume to be true, or must I prove it?

Comment: IMO you are over-complicating so much, just use the simple definition of the improper integral as a limit and my previous comment. Yes, you can divide the integral as many times as you can, its ever true that $\int_0^\infty g \ dx=\int_0^b g \ dx + \int_b^\infty g \ dx$, but I dont know if you need to prove it or not

Comment: @Masacroso I am? Could you elaborate? This is how we are told to do proofs at my uni.

Comment: @Masacroso But I never showed $\int_0^T |f(x)|dx$ exists?

Comment: @Masacroso What is wrong with what I wrote however? I basically showed that the integral is a cauchy sequence and consequently convergent? How is that over-complicating things?

Comment: yes, you are right, maybe Im used to do these things from a different way. Your way seems a more direct proof, that is, it is enough to show that $|\int_a^T f(t)dt|\le \int_a^T g(t) dt$ for any chosen $T\ge 0$ and any chosen $a\in[a,T]$